# A view inside another View, updated with AJAX

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a View of taxonomy terms (categories of books). This View lists all of the categories available to the user. Now I would like that, when the user clicks on the Category, a div will appear with a few books (another View, with contextual filter). By clicking on a link, I can go to the full View or to the details of the book, but if I do not click on any link, and go to another section and click on the title, I would like the earlier section to close the div, and another div with new books will appear in this new section.

The schema would be something like this:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

When clicking on Category 1, with AJAX there will appear:

- Category 1 ---> the next part appears retrieved with AJAX

  - Book 1
  - Book 2
  - Book 3
    See more books on Category 1 <--- END of content thrown by AJAX call.
- Category 2
- Category 3

I have been able to make it work without AJAX, using both modules [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion).

However, I cannot find out how to make it work with AJAX, so no tab content is loaded it will be loaded in AJAX when clicking and opening one tab category, so the browser memory/speed/server requeriment is not impacted if I just want to see books in one category.

[image]

Comment: why you need make it work with ajax? Are you dynamically updating any content in that section?

Comment: It is part of a more advanced feature. I would like to scroll down and make a "infinite scroll page" effect, loading more books. Obviously, I need to do it via AJAX (not from the beginning, but it could be), or I could crash the server loading hundreds of books at once. I will allow for a limit of AJAX calls, but seriously I need the possibility to achieve the effect.

Comment: did u check [Views Dynamic Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields)?

Comment: in Book view can't we use infinite scroll?

Comment: I do not understand Views Dynamic Fields, in isolation or with those 2 earlier modules? Yes, maybe I will try and install an infinite scroll module, but I though that it may be more simple task just to load with AJAX by now. I have the problem in the first place.  Imagine 30 categories with 10 books and no infinite scroll. With accordion you have 300 items loaded (a lot of resource consuming). With AJAX you only have 10 loaded each time. I have the two problems, so maybe mentioning infinite scroll is misleading, I still would like to load first instances of Accordion items with AJAX.

Comment: Hi @Cesar,  what is deadline for this task?( maybe I can write code for you tomorrow night,) are you a developer ? ( can you implement my solution ? my solution need some develop )

Comment: HI @zhilevan, you have almost 7 days. The bounty is 50 points. I would prefer some solution with no code at all, following this link preferences, but you are welcome if your code is elegant and see no other way of doing it. I am a developer struggling with Drupal. [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210522/if-there-are-so-many-modules-in-drupal-are-the-hard-coded-functions-reserved-on)

Comment: @Cesar bounty is not important for me, I just want help another person use drupal , I love drupal and try to help the others use drupal. i think your case is every custom and there is not way to completely achieve it with modules.

Comment: @zhilevan, I see your point. I would tend to agree on your view about custom module. My approach was this (I have not advanced since I wanted to extent all possibilites before that): [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212618/adding-a-jquery-interaction-with-views-accordion) . I tried to intercept the accordion "id" and fill the div with the jQueryAJAX view result, but it seemed too work. I played with QuickTabs but I think it is limited and not what I am searching (I believe it is static rather than dynamic). I do not see why it is so custom, it is almost accordion but with AJAX.

Comment: "I would prefer some solution with no code at all" - highly likely that that will not happen in this case. You want a custom AJAX action to do custom things. You should probably scale back the functionality and look at something like Views Show More, which will do the 'endless scroll' part but not the 'AJAX view within view' part. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_show_more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Module 'Views Ajax Get'

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ajax_get

Or you can also implement it on your own using below sample code, as Views itself provides callback /views/ajax for getting any view through Ajax -

PHP:

```
$view = views_get_view('taxonomy_term');
$view->set_display('page');
$view->set_use_ajax(TRUE);
$view->set_arguments(array($tid));
$settings = array(
  'views' => array(
    'ajax_path' => url('views/ajax'),
    'ajaxViews' => array(
      array(
        'view_name' => $view->name,
        'view_display_id' => $view->current_display,
        'view_args' => check_plain(implode('/', $view->args)),
        'view_path' => check_plain($_GET['q']),
        'view_base_path' => $view->get_path(),
        'view_dom_id' => 1,
        'pager_element' => $view->pager['element'],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
views_add_js('ajax_view');
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: Drupal.settings.views.ajax_path,
  type: 'GET',
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    var viewDiv = '.view-dom-id-' + data.view_dom_id;
    $('#content > div.limiter').html(response.display);
    // Call all callbacks.
    if (response.__callbacks) {
      $.each(response.__callbacks, function(i, callback) {
        eval(callback)(viewDiv, response);
      });
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    $('#content > div.limiter').html('<p id="artist-load-error">Error text.</p>');
    $('#block-request-0').hide();
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932523/embed-a-view-using-ajax

Answer (score 2):

[Views Megarow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow) sounds like it would be ideal for this situation as it opens up a new "accordion" page in the middle of your view like you desire.

You would need to build a new view page / panel page for the parent terms which list the books. This can be done in many ways but I guess a view for /categories/%tid would be the easiest.

The benefit is that you can really do a lot of stuff inside that page.. Blocks / Comments / Multiple Views etc. along with just listing books. If you already have pages for each category, it would be a case of creating a version suitable for loading inside the megarow.

It doesn't close the last category but I guess you could get past that with some basic jQuery.