# Adding a jQuery interaction with Views Accordion

Tags: 7, views, javascript, ajax, navigation

I have a [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) displaying some books under their categories.
I want to add some jQuery interaction, so when the user clicks the triangle of each category, the content will be loaded via jQuery AJAX.
How can I include this functionality? Something like this, though I cannot see any ID identifier associated with the href which opens / closes each of the accordion bellows.

```
 function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
     if($view->name == "categorias"){
         drupal_add_js('jQuery(function() {
             jQuery("#categorias-page-0").click(function(e) {
              // ... AJAX stuff
              });                    
         });', 'inline');
     } // if        
 } // function
```

Show image below, what I have, and when clicking on each category I would like to perform whatever jQuery actions I'd like.

[image]

Comment: This is a plain jQuery question. Drupal doesn't change how to use `$(this)` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` with out working on id/class.

Refer to this link [jQuery $(this) Selector with Examples](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector).

Answer (score 2):

Using suggestions by [#Nagarjuna](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/57682/nagarjuna) , I have updated the code so I can retrieve the internal ID of the accordion bellow. The only problem is that the numbers 0, 1, etc., are just a numbering, but using the same SORTING than the Views Query, they should match perfectly when accesing the content via AJAX.

```
 function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
   if($view->name == "categorias"){
     drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery(function () { 
       jQuery(\'a[href ^= "\' + "#categorias-page-" + \'"]\').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).click(function(){ 
              var clickado = (this + "");
              var categoria = clickado.split("-");
              alert(categoria[categoria.length - 1]);
            });
        });
    }); }(jQuery));', 'inline');
 } // if        
} // function
```